# Difference between "click" and "press"

Tags: verbs, differences

I want to know the difference between *click* and *press*. As we click the mouse and press a button. Where do we use *press* and where do we use *click*?

Comment: If, when you do the action, you hear a "click" sound, then it's a click.  Up until the "click" occurs it's a press.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly. I was in the process of rustling up some definitions for an answer - would you like to do the honours?

Comment: @Lawrence - No, have at it!  It's time for me to get breakfast.  (Wouldn't want to miss that!)

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, very well then :P . *Bon Appétit*!

Comment: how did a dictionary explain the difference?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence in which you think the two verbs are interchangeable. Failing that, this question does not really make much sense, as the two verbs mean very different things and are not generally interchangeable at all. Plus you've actually explained the difference yourself. You cannot click an elevator button IRL because there's no mouse involved. You can click it in a computer game, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, we use *"click"* for mice and buttons on the computer screen, and *"press"* for buttons which we physically push. Googling shows that some people do use *"press the mouse"* for the mouse button. However, I don't think anybody would say *"click floor 5"* for a button in an elevator. Similarly, unless it was designed for a touch screen, I think it would be quite rare to use *"press the **start** button"* for the image of a button which you have to activate by positioning the cursor over it and clicking the mouse.

**Speculative etymology follows; TL;DR**

Why? When mice were first invented in California, the inventors had to come up with a verb for "clicking" a mouse button. The verb they came up with was the one that stuck.

From this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=click+the+mouse%2Cclick+the+button%2Cpress+the+mouse%2Cpress+the+button&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclick%20the%20mouse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclick%20the%20button%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpress%20the%20mouse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpress%20the%20button%3B%2Cc0), it appears that *click* was first applied to mice, and then applied to buttons on the computer screen.

While it seems that the usual term in the U.K. is *press the button*, many Americans don't *press* buttons, they *push* buttons. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=press+the+button%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpress+the+button%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cpush+the+button%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpush+the+button%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpress%20the%20button%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpress%20the%20button%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpush%20the%20button%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpush%20the%20button%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).  I suspect this variation is regional, but I have no real evidence for this, and I don't know what the regional distribution of *press the button* and *push the button* is in the U.S.

Suppose the inventors of mice typically used *"push the button"*. It would have been clear to them that you couldn't say *"push the mouse"*, as that would be ambiguous: *"push the mouse"* might be interpreted as *"move the mouse"*. 
So they might have started using *"click"* as the verb.

It seems to me that *"press the mouse"* is completely unambiguous, and would have been a better choice than *"click"*. But maybe that word choice didn't even occur to the inventors of the mouse, because in their dialect, one didn't *press* buttons, one *pushed* them instead.

Comment: we use left click of mouse button but not use the left  push button ?

Comment: While *"left click the mouse"* is pretty clear, *"left push the mouse"* ***might*** be interpreted as move the mouse leftwards along the surface of your desk.

Comment: i want to ask Is we say press the button but when use mouse then say click the mouse.

Comment: I ***don't*** say "press the button"; I say "push the button". And you don't want to use "push the mouse", because that's ambiguous.

Comment: I think someone's pushing someone's buttons.  "Push" is rarely used (in the US) with regard to actions on a GUI device.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I'm talking about when mice were first invented. I've edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the historical context that went with it. Made a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Click is more of a software thing, while press is more of a hardware.

What it means is when there is physical touch involved in an action without any medium then its **press**. For example you ***press*** the button on the wall, or press the cross button on your mobile phone.

Click involves a medium. So when you use a mouse or a pointer to do the pressing for an action; you are clicking.

So you click the cross button on a desktop, while you press it on a touch screen mobile phone.

Comment: I'm confused ... pressing a button seems physical, like clicking a mouse.

Comment: Actually the name came into being because of the click on a mouse has a sound **click**. Is it clearer?

Comment: So my keyboard is unplugged it doesn't **click**??  What's that sound I hear, then?

Comment: @hot-licks You are right actually. The sound was called [clickety clack](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/clickety-clack).

Comment: @AamBoli - No, "clickety-clack" is the sound of a train rolling over a **real** railroad track, one before they installed those stupid welded rails and made it all quiet-like.

Answer (score 0):

First, some definitions:

> **Click**
> *noun* 1 A short, sharp sound as of a switch being operated or of two hard objects coming smartly into contact
> *noun* 1.2 Computing An act of pressing a button on a mouse or similar device:
> *verb* 1.1 Computing Select an item in a graphical user interface by pressing a button on a mouse
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/click)
>
> **Press** *verb*
> Move or cause to move into a position of contact with something by exerting continuous physical force
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/press)

*Press* is more generic. A click *is* a press, but a press *may not be* a click.

Of the *click* definitions, *verb 1.1* is the closest to your question. It is related to *noun 1.2*, which in turn is related to the more general *noun 1*. *Click* is an onomatopoeia that is related to the sound that the mouse button button makes when pressing it activates the mechanical switch underneath.

In **answer** to your question: the difference between *click* and *press* is that *click* evokes the audible (and perhaps even tangible) feedback from the mouse, whereas *press* simply refers to the generic action of pushing the button.